# Como agregar el elemento reporting en Visual C# 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Tengo instalado Visual Studio Community 2017, el problema es que agregue el Report Viewer pero a la hora de agregar un elemento nuevo especificamente el informe, no me aparece en agregar nuevo elemento. No aparece el renglon Reporting.

He intentado agregarlo volviendo a ejecutar el instalador para seleccionar la herramienta SQL Server Data Tools y esta incluida.

Necesito ayuda con este problema.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score -2):

Dentro del IDE en la pestaña `Herramientas`, seleccionas `extensiones` y actualizaciones y descargas el ítem que dice "Diseñador de infromes RDLC".

Cuando completes la descarga debes cerrar Visual Studio para que se realicen los cambios.

Después de esto puedes irte a nuevo elemento y encontrarás la opción "Informe" o "Reporting" dependiendo del idioma que hayas elegido y continuar con el proyecto.